# Root path in the *.properties file

Tags: java, configuration, jakarta-ee

I have a *.properties file with some configurations in it, there I have a "file=" key where I need to specify the path to the file. Now, my file is situated in root folder of my web application. How can I specify root of my web application in *.proprietes file?

Something like

```
file=${root}/file.extension
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read your property file in the web application, programatically replace `${root}` with `getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`

Comment: Sounds interesting, how you can add a getServletContext().getRealPath("/"); in the something.proprietes? :)

Comment: You can't, like epoch said, you have to specify that you want the root folder in your properties file and then translate it when you read it.

Comment: @hoss, nope, you would not be able to do that, i mean where you physically read the property file then you replace your root variable with the result of the call.

Comment: @Dmitri, @epoch, an example please?

Comment: Um, `myProps.getProperty("file").replace("${root}", getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));`.  Assuming you're somewhere where you have access to the servlet context.

Comment: @Dmitri, I cannot do that, because with this *.proprietes file I am connecting to the remote server, it's not the best way. I need to do that in *.proprietes file itself. I am not passing it to the JavaAction class :)

Comment: How do you expect your .properties file to know where your web root is? Or anything to do with web applications, for that matter.

Comment: I solved this with Properties class in JavaAction class by putting: props.setProperty("file", context.getRealPath("/") + "filename.ext");